# Наречия «с лёту» и «с лёта». Различия и особенности

Tags: семантика, наречия, выбор-варианта

Каковы различия в значениях наречий **с лёту** и **с лёта**?
Есть ли особенности, оттенки значений? Если нет, какой вариант лучше использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наречия ***с лёта*** и ***с лёту*** не различаются по значению, в словаре Ефремовой они указаны вместе:

**С Лета и С Лету**, нареч. разг. 1. Не останавливая полета. // перен. Не прекращая очень быстрого, стремительного движения. 2. перен. Легко, быстро, мгновенно, без усилий (схватывать, понимать и т.п.); на лету.

1) Вариант ***с лёту*** используется достаточно часть (106 примеров в Нацкорпусе), можно на нём остановиться.

Пример: Часть отступающих **с лету** нарвалась на разъезд улан  [Борис Васильев. Были и небыли. Книга 2 (1988)]

Вариант ***с лёта*** графически совпадает с вариантом ***с лета***, если не обозначается буква Ё (это не очень удобно).

**3) Пояснение** (почему существуют две формы)

В Р.п. ед. числа существительных м. рода встречаются **варианты окончаний** –а (-я) и -у (-ю). Например: снега – снегу; блеска – блеску.

Это варьирование – свидетельство древнего процесса **объединения нескольких склонений в одно**. Вариант –у (-ю) постепенно вытесняется более продуктивным –а (-я). Устаревающую форму в современном языке сохраняют только **некоторые разряды имен существительных.**

В современном литературном языке употребление варианта –у (-ю) оправдано в случаях, когда их используют:

- для выражения степени действия, состояния или качества: *с голоду, с испугу, до отказу, наделать шуму, сколько визгу, спору нет.*

Подробно: https://studfiles.net/preview/4259563/